# Тире как авторский знак

Tags: пунктуация

Известно, что тире может ставиться по правила русского языка (например, перед "это", в оформлении прямой речи или диалога и т.д.), а может являться авторским знаком. Так вот, хотелось бы узнать, в каких ситуациях уместно поставить это самое авторское тире? Какие интонации или оттенки речи оно может подчеркнуть? И когда можно запятую заменить тире (насколько я понимаю, пунктуационно в некоторых ситуациях они могут быть равноправными).

Answer (score 3):

В книге Розенталя "Пунктуация" есть **§ 72. Вариативные знаки препинания**: http://www.libok.net/writer/9403/kniga/100123/rozental_ditmar_elyashevich/punktuatsiya/read/39 и дальше.

Там подробно описано, когда уместно ставить **тире вместо двоеточия, запятой, скобок** и т.д.

Следующий раздел (20) называется **"Авторская пунктуация"**. Вообще под авторской пунктуацией понимают:

1.Преимущественное использование автором одного из знаков препинания (доминантный знак), индивидуальное расширение функций этого знака, не нарушающее правил.

2.Экспериментальные знаки препинания и их сочетания, нарушающие правила.

*Нужно было по сбитым, источенным ступенькам ( – молодая крапивка росла из каменных трещин – ) спуститься в полуподвал* (Леонов).

3.Нарушение правил пунктуации, связанное с заменой нейтрального или нулевого знака более сильным.

*Маша кинулась ему на шею, и зарыдала* (Пушкин).

Что касается функций авторских тире, они многообразны, поэтому так много исследований пунктуационных особенностей отдельных текстов.

Например, Блок активно использовал тире для сжатого, резкого и контрастного выражения мыслей, в ритмомелодических целях как отражение жестких пауз.

*…Скалит зубы — волк голодный —*

*Хвост поджал — не отстаёт —*

*Пёс холодный — пёс безродный…*

Цветаева употребляет тире для смыслового выделения последнего слова строки, для создания особой ритмомелодии стиха, чеканного слога.

*Июльский ветер мне метёт — путь,*

*И где-то музыка в окне — чуть.*

*Ах, нынче ветру до зари — дуть*

*Сквозь стенки тонкие груди — в грудь.*

Пильняк употребляет последовательность из двух и более тире в позиции одного пунктуационного знака, что усиливает эффект неожиданности.

*...В голове окончательно спутаны мозги,бред, ерунда, а желудок, кишечник, — желудок лезет в горло, в рот — — — — и тогда всё всё-равно, безразлично, нету качки, — единственная реальность — море, бред, ерунда — —.*

И так далее до бесконечности.

Comment: Согласно Розенталю, после обобщающего слова перед однородным рядом встречается наряду с обычным двоеточием также тире. А что меняется при этом с точки зрения смысла? Как интересуется автор вопроса, "какие интонации или оттенки речи оно (тире) может подчеркнуть"? Казалось бы, такой анализ  следовало провести для выбора нужного знака. Но кажется, в те времена больше рассчитывали на авторскую интуицию?

Comment: Есть 2 направления анализа: можно анализировать, как меняется смысловой оттенок, отталкиваясь от традиционных функций тире, а можно говорить о расширении функций тире за счет других знаков. Согласно современным исследованиям авторской пунктуации (читай: пунктуации СМИ) тире отнимает у других знаков их функции, становясь универсальным знаком. Это проще для пишущего, но сложнее для читающего.

Comment: Это большая проблема для работников СМИ: приходится угадывать, вместо какого знака автор употребил тире, не возникает ли двусмысленности в предложении, перегруженном тире, и в каких местах его целесообразно заменить другим знаком, не нарушив авторскую пунктуацию. Научного материала на эту тему очень мало - в основном просто фиксируют тенденции массового отступления от правил. Непаханое поле.

Comment: Tat, у Вас просто талант  к обобщению, но мы-то решаем конкретные задачи. Вот предложение: (1) Легенды и сказки любят все: и дети, и взрослые. Или: (2)Легенды и сказки любят все - и дети, и взрослые. Есть смысловое различие? Разная интонация? Какой вариант лучше?

Answer (score 0):

Можете здесь прочитать:http://www.xliby.ru/jazykoznanie/spravochnik_po_pravopisaniyu_proiznosheniyu_literaturnomu_redaktirovaniyu/p3.php#metkadoc7

Answer (score 0):

Авторское тире, как и любой авторский знак, имеет следующие особенности:
1) не соответствует правилам постановки основного знака; 2) вносит новый оттенок смысла;  3) изменяет интонацию предложения.

Современный знак тире, в соответствии с интонацией,  имеет две разновидности: разделительное тире и присоединительное тире.

Авторское тире заменяет  основные знаки (запятую, двоеточие) или является дополнительным знаком. Использование авторского тире удобно рассмотреть на конкретных примерах.

1) Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым.

Эта тема регулируется большим количеством правил,  но практически на каждое правило есть авторское исключение. Постановка  авторского тире определяется по наличию паузы: "Ты – вечности заложник у времени в плену". "Нет, бытие – не зыбкая загадка!" "Я весь – как взмах неощутимых крыл".

2)  Тире заменяет запятую и используется в качестве неосновного знака в СПП и ССП.

Это разделительное тире, обозначающее увеличенную паузу: "Ещё сотня шагов – и показались штабеля брёвен". "Стали искать черкесов во всех кустах – и, разумеется, ничего не нашли". "Сколько бы ни смотреть на море – оно никогда не надоест". "Коли ты честный – не водись с бесчестными".  "Когда идёшь над бездной – надо прямо смотреть в лазурь и свет".

3) Авторское тире заменяет двоеточие в БСП.

Каждый знак в БСП  (запятая, тире, двоеточие) обозначает определенный вид отношений с соответствующей интонацией и  регулируется правилами.

Двоеточие как основной знаки используется для обозначения изъяснительных, пояснительных и следственно-причинных отношений, при этом его во всех случаях может заменять авторское (разделительное или присоединительное) тире.  Для двоеточия характерно понижение тона перед увеличенной (предупредительной) паузой, а при постановке тире такая пауза отсутствует.  Авторское тире или подчеркивает деление предложения на две части, или обозначает добавочный характер второго сообщения.

«Вижу – дело плохо!»  Здесь разделительное тире (повышение тона перед паузой).  «Всё стало понятно – на поляне кормилась лошадь, а где-то здесь, рядом, кто-то ночевал". "Пора ехать – всё уже готово». В этих примерах присоединительное тире (с понижением тона перед  небольшой паузой).

4) Примером равноправного выбора могут служить неполные предложения, а также обособление приложений с помощью запятой или тире. В этом случае интонационная структура имеет принципиальное значение:

"Тёркин – дальше, автор – вслед" (параллельная интонация). Татьяна в лес, медведь за нею (нет параллельной интонации).

Вот она, безграничная и  необозримая степь (две фразы, разделенные паузой). - Вот она наконец – безграничная, необозримая степь (перед присоединительным с пояснительным значением тире делается понижение тона).